# Insert "Multiple Field Value" in the Same Column in MVC4?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, angularjs, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to save the Multiple field Values in the same Column.

**TaxField** Table contain 3 Fields

1)TaxFieldID
2)DisplayName
3)PrintName

TaxFieldID  = FD713788-B5AE-49FF-8B2C-F311B9CB0CC4

DisplayName = TinNo

PrintName   = TinNo

The value of TinNo CinNo etc all are  have default value which is saved in TaxField Table

**TaxInfoTaxField Table**

[image]

My View contain six fields **TinNo, CstNo, PanNo, ServiceTaxNo,ExciseRegNo, CinNo.**

Format to save the Value and ID in TaxInfoTaxFieldTable

TinNo = FD713788-B5AE-49FF-8B2C-F311B9CB0CC4

CstNo = 64B512E7-46AE-4989-A049-A446118099C4

CinNo =59A2449A-C5C6-45B5-AA00-F535D83AD48B

[image]

My Model

```
    public partial class TaxInfoTaxFiled
        {
            public System.Guid TaxInfoTaxFieldID { get; set; }
            public Nullable TaxInfoID { get; set; }
            public Nullable TaxFieldID { get; set; }
            public Nullable FieldTypeID { get; set; }
            public string FieldValue { get; set; }
}
    public partial class TaxField
        {
            public System.Guid TaxFieldID { get; set; }
            public string DisplayName { get; set; }
            public string PrintName { get; set; }
}
```

MyViewModel

```
    public class TaxViewModel1
    {
        public System.Guid TaxInfoTaxFieldID { get; set; }
        public System.Guid TaxInfoID { get; set; }
        public Nullable TaxFiledID { get; set; }
        public string TinNo { get; set; }
        public string CstNo { get; set; }
        public string ExciseRegNo { get; set; }
        public string PanNo { get; set; }
        public string ServiceTaxNo { get; set; }
        public string CinNo { get; set; }
    }
    public class VisitorsEntities1 : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet TaxField { get; set; }
        public DbSet TaxInfo { get; set; }
        public DbSet TaxInfoTaxFiled { get; set; }
    }
```

My Controller

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(TaxViewModel1 TVM)
    {
        Type type = typeof(TaxField);
         PropertyInfo[] Info = new         
    TaxInfoTaxField().GetType().GetProperties();

        foreach (TaxInfoTaxField property in properties)
        {
         var Value = property.GetValue(TVM.TinNo, null);
            var Value1 = property.GetValue(TVM.CstNo, null);
        }
        return View(Tax);
    }
```

Sir In this below  Code we pass the Properties of TaxField and it is get by TaxinfoTaxField Table

```
Type type = typeof(TaxField);
PropertyInfo[] Info = new TaxInfoTaxField().GetType().GetProperties();
```

And in 'foreach Loop ' we assigning the Value to the Variable. But how to assign the value to the Column .And How to do save the Value in FieldValue and ID in TaxFieldID of TaxInfoTaxField Table in the above format which I mentioned. Please Correct my Controller Code . I am very very new to MVC . so only I struggling for this Small Concepts. Please correct my Controller Code and help me to save the Values in the TaxInfoTaxField table. And if you have a times means please explain me the Logic used in Controller.

Thanks.

Comment: You need to create the object and asign values to it and then save it. By the way are you using reflection here?

Comment: Raider Please elaborate your answer with some eg

Comment: Can you explain why you have to use reflection here?

Comment: Because here my table is designed in that format .Iam using Existing table.